# Why doesnt my Scss mixin work in my React Project?

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, react-router

So I have a new React Project where im trying SCSS for the styling part. Im basically a SCSS noob as I've always used Css. I went online to find tutorials on how to do it and i got this code in the end:

```
// _themes.scss
$themes: (
    light: (
        color-background: #FAFAFA,
        color-card: #FFF
    ),
    dark: (
        color-background: #37474F,
        color-card: #212121
    )
);

// _mixins.scss
@mixin theme-aware($key, $color) {
    @each $theme-name, $theme-color in $themes {
        .theme-#{$theme-name} & {
            #{$key}: map.get(map.get($themes, $theme-name), $color)
        }
    }
}

//App.module.scss

@import "../../assets/themes/mixins";

.container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    @include theme-aware('background', 'color-background');
}
```

Now I've tried about everything:

- Tried to remove the module from the style sheet turning fixinf the imports
- Define the mixins in the App.module.scss
- Put everying (as in themes and mixins) in the App.module.scss

Here is what I know and understand so far:

- The .theme-#{$theme-name} will apply to the current theme that is applied to the html parent element
- This application is running and it currently switches between  and  (I have also tried to apply the styling to the React root element with no success)
- When i define other mixins, simpler ones, not envolving map-get it works perfectly
- Im using Dart Sass seen in npm [here][1]

What am I not understanding? The tutorial i saw online used node-scss and worked, so far is the only difference i can find

EDIT:: I finally found the issue. It does work IF I dont use React Router. My App.tsx:

```
export default function App() {

    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    const session = useSelector(sessionSelector)
    const theme = useSelector(themeSelector)

    useEffect(() => {
        document.documentElement.className = '';
        document.documentElement.classList.add(`theme-${theme.name}`)
    }, [theme])

    return (
        <div>
            <Home />
            <Routes>
                <Route path={paths.home} element={<Outlet />}>
                    <Route element={<RequireAuth roles={["SUPER"]} />}>

                    </Route>

                    <Route element={<RequireAuth roles={["SUPER", "ADMIN"]} />}>

                    </Route>

                    <Route element={<RequireAuth roles={["SUPER"]} />}>

                    </Route>
                </Route>
            </Routes>
        </div>
    )
}
```

As you can see, I apply the scss theme to the document itself. It does work in my  component and all colors change, but the routes do not recognize the class. To fix it i applied the style to the body like:

```
@import "./assets/themes/mixins";

* {
    @include theme-aware('background', 'color-background');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is there in `_mixins.scss` , you need to import of `sass:map` to use `map.get` or else you can also use `map-get` directly without importing `sass:map` and I have replaced hyphen in `.theme-#{$theme-name}` in `mixins.scss` with underscore `.theme_#{$theme-name}`. With these two changes in the code you provided the appropriate theme is getting applied.

```
// _themes.scss
 $themes: (
light: (
    color-background: #FAFAFA,
    color-card: #FFF
),
dark: (
    color-background: #37474F,
    color-card: #212121
)
);

   // _mixins.scss
   @use "sass:map";
   @import "./themes";

   @mixin theme-aware($key, $color) {
       @each $theme-name, $theme-color in $themes {
          .theme_#{$theme-name} & {
             #{$key}: map.get(map.get($themes, $theme-name), $color);
       }
      }
    }

 //App.module.scss
  @import "./mixins";

 .container {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
       @include theme-aware('background-color','color-background');
   } 


//App.module.scss
import styles from "./app.module.scss";

export default function App() {
     return (
         <div className={styles.theme_dark}>
             <div className={styles.container}>
                <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
                <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
             </div>
         </div>
      );
    }
```

[image: Working Example]
Working Example you can find here:- https://codesandbox.io/s/customised-theme-6dvt04?file=/src/_mixins.scss

Comment: Same result. Nothing changed. I can't quite understand if im just too noob to see why or its some actual bug that I'm unaware

Comment: I have found the issue and updated the answer .Hope it works for you now.

Comment: Does this work? What do you mean with &? I understood its like class nesting but i don't quite see how to fix it as it isnt working still

Comment: Can you provide some stackblitz example to show your approach? Can find out the issue the issue there.

Comment: I have updated the question. see that your example doesnt work to me... idk why

Comment: I was considering that your theme class is nested inside container class , but since container is nested inside theme class , accordingly I have updated the answer.

Comment: Im going to try to rewrite everything like you have and test it. chance are I made some idiotic mistake i can't recognize

Comment: Will aplying the themed container to the app div apply it to all children? Including using react-router?

Answer (score 0):

> You didn't use .scss extension in react if you don't use JavaScript then make sure add that language extension..

```
@import 
"../../assets/themes/_mixins.scss"; 
      Or
```

If your mixin scss file name not contain (_) underscore then use this

```
@import 
"../../assets/themes/mixins.scss;
```

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Because it works sometimes and i did say i have an extension, Dart scss so im quite confused